# Can I use my router as modem?

Tags: networking, router, modem

So my Phone + Internet company gave me a modem-router (some Huawei model) that accepts a normal phone line (RJ12) as input and 4 LAN ports (RJ45) that I connect my PCs to. My question is, can I use my router's modem capabilities to place normal phone calls (i.e. use my PC as phone)? Does it depend upon the exact router model, or is it simply not possible and I'll have to buy a separate modem card and install it in my PC and then connect my phone line directly with that modem card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need a phone to place a normal phone call. Modems exchange digital data over phone lines. The modem filters out the portion of the spectrum used for normal voice calls.

Comment: Are you sure? I recall I have used a modem card back in 1997-98 that would install in the PCI slot and I'd connect my phone line directly with it. I then used to send/receive calls using a software named Fax Pro or Fax It or something (don't even remember its name after 20-so years).

Comment: @dotNET Yeah, I'm sure. That's a completely different animal.

Comment: Looks like you're right then, though I didn't want to hear that. :-S

Answer (score 1):

Your modem is an ADSL (or VDSL) modem, it doesn't do touch tone signalling. Get a DSL splitter and use a second cable to your phone device, be it a PCI card or just a regular handset.

VOIP may be a better and cheaper solution here. You can do it all from your PC with no new hardware at all.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I do have a splitter. The other cable is going into a regular handset. I was wondering if I could instead use a software on my PC to do handset's job (in a better way of course). Looks like I must buy a Voice Modem.

Comment: A managed voip service may still be better as you can have it ring in multiple locations(including on your mobile, or several), have intelligent divert etc. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a [dialup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dial-up_Internet_access) modem, you can place a phone call or fax from the modem, because it modulates digital signal directly onto voice frequency, resulting in the very distinctive tones that you can hear.

However I assume you're using an ADSL modem, because dialup modems are very hard to find nowadays and they are highly unlikely to have RJ-45 ports (they use a single COM port or similar low speed connectors). ADSL protocols are very different. They use a different frequency range outside the voice range, so the modem will filter out those frequencies.

You need to use a splitter. Its ADSL output will have the voice frequencies filtered out, and the phone output will be free of ADSL signals. You can still connect a dialup modem into to the phone output to place a phone call or send a fax.